# How do I retrieve a color of type UIColor from another function?

Tags: swift, function, uicolor

I am receiving the following error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. I am trying to store the value of `currentConfiguration[0]` from the `panGesture` function, to variable `currentColor` in my `getRandomColor` function. Any ideas? I believe the solution is likely simple but I am not too familiar with Swift functions.

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
    let colors = [UIColor.redColor(),
                  UIColor.blueColor(),
                  UIColor.greenColor(),
                  UIColor.yellowColor(),
                  UIColor.purpleColor(),
                  UIColor.magentaColor()]

    // Generate a random index
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
    // Get a random item
    let randomColor = colors[randomIndex]

    var currentColor = panGesture()
    return randomColor
}

func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> (UIColor?) {

    let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view!)

    let face1 = UIColor.redColor()
    let face2 = UIColor.blueColor()
    let face3 = UIColor.greenColor()
    let face4 = UIColor.yellowColor()
    let face5 = UIColor.purpleColor()
    let face6 = UIColor.magentaColor()

    let viewColor = sceneSetup()

    //Initialize array to store current cube configuration i.e. face location
    var currentConfiguration = [face1,face2,face3,face4,face5,face6]
    var updatedConfiguration = [face1,face2,face3,face4,face5,face6]

    return currentConfiguration[0]
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `var currentColor = panGesture(()` would not compile and you'd get a warning because it's after the `return`. Show your real code and explain what line gets what error message.

Comment: What's this?  func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> (UIColor?)

Comment: The panGesture function takes user pan gestures to rotate a cube and I am trying to return the color of the front face of the cube which is always the first value in the currentConfiguration array. The error: 'Missing argument for parameter #1 in call', is being thrown on var currentColor = panGesture() .

Answer (score 0):

`panGesture()` takes a parameter, per its definition. Your call `var currentColor = panGesture()` does not supply one.

Note also that `panGesture()` returns a `UIColor?`, which you must unwrap before returning from `getRandomColor()`.